# How to fix #0c:e9 with lotuscript

Tags: lotus-notes

Lotus Notes R9 Client show #0c:e9 when open specific document, 
The error #0c:e9 appear when richtext field exists on Form, so I am sure the error came from richtext field.
Is it possible to use lotusscript or tool to fix this document.

Comment: I had this error as well. I was able to open up the document via a web i/f. It's a mail-in db so I was able to read the email and respond. I had to eventually delete the document. We'll see if subsequent emails from that company causes this problem again. clem

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps to set an additional parameter in your notes.ini: No_Div_Width=1.

See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO52287

Answer (score 0):

First of all, an error code dialog like #0c:09 is the result of an unhandled error in lower layers of the Notes client code. That means it's a bug in client. You should be talking to IBM about that.

Now, since you've concluded that the bug is being driven by something in the rich text, I have to tell you that your chances of fixing it via LotusScript code are pretty slim. Your only chance, IMHO, would be to write code to use the NotesDXLExporter class to try to export it to an XML file. If that actually succeeds without also running into a bug reading the rich text, then you can attempt to go through a manual trial-and-error process of editing the XML to remove or modify anything that looks suspect to you, and then re-importing the DXL into a local replica of your database and opening the document to see if the error goes away.

In all likelihood, though, simply re-creating the content of the document is probably going to be easier.

Comment: I will try this solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: richtext item seems encoded with MIME. After DXLImport one of the rawitemdata. Error Message become #0C:02. rawitemdata format looks like this <item name='Content'>
<rawitemdata type='1'>
gv9aAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAIBwAAC...</rawitemdata></item>

Comment: rawitemdata can decode with base64 decoder. and generate almost the correct text